# How to fix 'XCtests failing intermittently to launch app in the simulator' in Xcode 10

Tags: xcuitest

When I try to run my test cases in simulator, I'm getting this error:

> "Failure requesting automation session for com.name.name:61876:
>   Timeout waiting for fulfillment of promise for 'Requesting automation
>   session for com.name.name" when app launch time in Xcode 10.

Comment: i'm seeing this same issue.  Any luck?  Mine is occurring when running tests in parallel

Answer (score 1):

It seems that before the app finish to launch/activate you are trying to perform another task in the app.

i.e trying to activate the app again